# Add Frames to images in HTML5

Tags: html, html5-canvas, border, image-editing

I am new to HTML5 . I want to create one application where i can add borders / frames to images in gallery or new pictures taken from device camera and save the image with borders . User Should be able to select the frames from available list and place the frame on the camera and save it later  I am able to use the getusermedia api and access the webcam from browser via html5 . I have searched a lot but could nt find a solution :(

Comment: Learn about canvas' **context.drawImage method** that draws images to the canvas (like your webcam image and your frame image). First draw your image with `context.drawImage(webImage,0,0)` and then draw your frame around the image `context.drawImage(frame,0,0);`

Comment: Did you try using JavaScript? :)